# PostgreSQL current server name

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

i need to get the server's name that is listed on pgAdmin NOT the host name or IP Address, but the real server name that appears on pgAdmin, a host can contain several servers so i don't want `inet_server_addr()`, i need to write something maybe on plpythonu like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Current_Server()
  RETURNS varchar
AS $$
    try:
        return environ.get('SERVERNAME');
    except:
        return 'dummy localhost';
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

or any code on PLPGSQL or any other language will be just fine.
on pgAdmin you can get the server name by right clicking on the server and then properties:

[image: pgAdmin Shortcut]

so how and where does pgAdmin get that name from?

also it's gonna be nice to have the whole server list too.

Comment: That name is just something that pgAdmin uses so that you can organize your connections - you entered that name when you created the connection. It has nothing to do with the actual server where Postgres runs

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53634/save-export-pgadmin-server-list-configuration-settings

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually yes, i was looking for the server connection names that are on pgAdmin

Comment: You can't do that with a SQL function  - those are stored in the pgAdmin configuration files, not in the Postgres server

Comment: @eurotrash the answer in the link was written by a_horse_with_no_name could've be just fine but it doesn't work any more on Postgresql 11 only on Postgresql 10

Comment: pgAdmin 4 doesn't save the connections on regedit anymore

Comment: @ZORRO_BLANCO There's an answer at the end that appears to address PGAdmin 4: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193093/132647

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the info so i don't look anymore for such a method :)